# Oracle SQL - How to format output without showing the explicit value

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting, anonymize

I'm making a query on a table of exam results. A student passes the exam if the score is above 50 %. I want the output of the query to show 1 if the exam score is above 50% (i.e. exam is passed) and 0 if the score is below 50% (i.e. exam s failed). I do not want the actual exam score to be shown.

```
    TURN THIS               INTO                 THIS
Exam no.   Score                          Exam no.   Score   
   1        37%              =>              1         0
   2        84%                              2         1
   3        76%                              3         1
```

How do I do this? I've found several articles and pages on formatting the result with spaces, linebraks, renaming of coloumns etc., but I cannot figure out how to use "representational values".

Is there a way to write the query so that the result will look like the one in my example above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CASE expression:

```
select exam_no, 
       case 
          when score >= 50 then 1
          else 0
       end as score
from the_table;
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the case expressson. It does exactly what I need :)